# Pegar a hora do banco de dados MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, crud

-Boa noite, pessoal!

Eu tenho uma aplicação que pega dados do banco de dados e apresenta na tela. É uma grade horária de televisão, ou seja, mostra o que está passando ao vivo e o que vai passar depois.

O tipo de dados que representa a hora da programação é **DateTime**

Gostaria de pegar somente a hora e o minuto, ignorando a data. 
Exemplo: no banco está assim (2019-08-31 20:50) Quero pegar apenas o 20:50 e mostrar na tela. Estou fazendo com php.

Como posso fazer isso?

Meu código atual:

```
<?php
//SELECT
$gh_resultado = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM Programacao where horario >= '$gh_data' order by horario");

//Mostrando na tela
echo $gh_resultado[0]->horario;
?>
```

Comment: Utilize a função TIME(seu_campo_datetime) do MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como já explicado só utilizar a função TIME() do mysql
Exemplo.:

```
SELECT *, TIME(horario) AS horario FROM Programacao where horario >= '$gh_data' order by horario
```

Lembrando que o nome da propriedade a ser retornada mudara para TIME(propriedade), então é importante que a renomeie novamente para seu antigo nome como

```
TIME(horario) AS horario
```

Comment: Deu certo! Muito obrigado pela ajuda!!!!